# override existing files in Downloads on GitHub

Tags: github

Is there a way to override the file in the Downloads section on GitHub when uploading a file with the same filename? (e.g. via developer API or the [ruby script](https://github.com/github/upload), etc) The reason is that I want to keep track of the number of downloads. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's cool if it can. Maybe you can send e-mail to `support@github.com`

Answer (score 1):

I havn't tried this but it's possible that you could replace the file on Amazon S3. I don't know if it will work or if it's a one-time upload token you get without the posibility to delete the file.

See the API documentation for uploading a file on Github (which includes using the amazon s3 rest api to upload the file):

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/

And API documentation for deleing a file on amazon s3:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html

And API documentation for putting a file on amazon s3:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html